# what is the truth table for A subset B?

Tags: logic

Let me explain we know that:
XOR (exclusive-or) ≡ symmetric difference = (A-B) ∪ (B-A).

we know that:
XNOR (¬XOR i.e. negation of XOR) ≡ ↔ (Bi-condontional statement) =  A=B iff (if and only if) B=A.

we know that:
A-B (set difference) ≡ PΛ¬Q ≡ ¬(P→Q).

we know that:
A∩B ≡ PΛQ

we know that:
A∪B ≡ PνQ

I know this because I worked it out last night here are the truth tables in this PDF:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nc8201ccwwis4hi/truth%20tables.pdf?dl=0

now comes the fun part I have absolutely no idea what the hell are the truth tables for these:

- A ⊆ B
- A ⊂ B
- A ⊇ B
- A ⊃ B

also what are the truth tables for negation of these sets:

- ¬(A ⊆ B)
- ¬(A ⊂ B)
- ¬(A ⊇ B)
- ¬(A ⊃ B)

Please Somebody help my brain is wrecked and I can't think any more about this stuff. Let me know if there is anything you need I'd be happy to try and answer.

Comment: You make truth tables for boolean expressions involving truth values $0,1$. $A\subset B$ does not make sense when $A,B$ are truth values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misreading the "equivalences" above.

It is not true that $A \cap B \equiv P \land Q$.

$P \land Q$ is a statement whose truth value is either True or False.

$A \cap B$ is the "name" of a set: the intersection of sets $A$ and $B$.

But there is a link between the two: $A \cap B$ is defined by formula $(x \in A \land x \in B)$, that means:

> $\forall x \ [x \in (A \cap B) \leftrightarrow (x \in A \land x \in B)]$.

Things are similar for $\subseteq$ (and all the "derived" ones), but there is a difference: $A \subseteq B$ is not a "name" for a set but a statement involving two sets, and its definition is:

> $A \subseteq B \leftrightarrow \forall x ( x \in A \to x \in B)$.

In conclusion: there is a link between boolean connectives: $\lnot, \land \lor, \to$ and set operations: complement, intersection, union, inclusion, but we cannot simply equate them.

---

Having said that, in principle when can use truth tables to "check $A \subseteq B$ when $A$ and $B$ are finite sets.

But what is the benefit for e.g. $A = \{ 0, 1, 3, 7 \}$ and $B = \mathbb N$ to write the truth table with four lines and two columns to verify te statement $A \subseteq B$ ?

Comment: A truth table for the statement $A\subseteq B$ gives us the value of the statement $0/1$ for each value of $A$ and $B$. Since $A,B$ are not $0/1$, we have infinite possibilities even when both sets are finite. How can you draw the truth table?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri - NO. If $A$ is finite, it is enough to check **all** elements of $A$.

Comment: You have selected particular sets for $A,B$. That is like selecting $p(x)=1,q(x)=1$ and concluding $p(x)\wedge q(x)=1$ is the truth table for the statement $p(x)\wedge q(x)$...?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri - **IF** $A$ is finite, whatever it is, it is enough to check the elements in $A$. For the example above, $\pi \notin A$; thus $\pi \in A \to \pi \in \mathbb N$ is TRUE.